# Check existing mail with ajax and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Is there any method to check if the mail (in a registration form) exist in my database while i'm writing it (before i click submit buttom).

This is my javascript function it work well when I click submit button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){ //newly added 
    $('#_submit').click(function() {alert('in');
      var emailVal = $('#mail').val(); // assuming this is a input text field
       $.post('checkemail.php', {'mail' : emailVal}, function(data) {
         if(data=='exist') return false;
         else $('#form1').submit();
      });
    });
 });
</script>
```

but I want to verify the mail before I submit (without I click any button)

Comment: What exactly is not working properly? Where is your HTML form? What is your desired output?

Comment: I think you need to bind your actions to the form submit event, instead of to the click event on the submitbutton

Comment: @RichardBernards I have a simple form with submit button, all I want is : when I write the mail and I pass to the next field, I want to be alerted if the email is already exist. If mail fild ok, then I can click on my submit buttom to register informations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `#_submit` is a submit button. In that case, your `<from>` will be submitted without waiting for the ajax call to complete, since that is an **asynchronous** task.

In order to work around this, you should prevent the `<form>` submission by default, and once the ajax call completes, decide whether to submit the form or not depending on the response.

```
$(document).ready(function() { //newly added 
  $('#_submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default submission
    alert('in, submission prevented - waiting for ajax response');
    var emailVal = $('#mail').val(); // assuming this is a input text field
    $.post('checkemail.php', {
      'mail': emailVal
    }, function(data) {
      if (data == 'exist')
        return false;
      else
        $('#form1').submit();
    });
  });
});
```

or you can simply use a `type="button"` button so that it doesn't trigger `<form>` submission.

Answer (score -2):

something like that

```
$.ajax(url).done(function(response) {
if (response === true) {
     $(form).submit();
} else {
   console.log("not allowed");
});
```

Comment: read the question properly, OP already has this system in place using `$.post()`